# Getting an empty Array of Products in React native Iap

Tags: reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, payment, react-native-iap

Hey I am using React native iap with react native 0.64.2. Also I am using razor pay in it also.

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
"react-native-iap": "7.5.1",
"react-native-razorpay": "^2.3.0",




const itemSkus = Platform.select({
    ios:["com.app.plandetailed"]
  });
const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
console.log('Products', products);
```

As the products console is empty and I added itemSkus as well. But it tried with
"react-native":"0.65.1"
"react-native-iap": "12.10.5"

but nothing worked my products status[image]

let me know if anybody have an idea of it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call function with skus.
here is example:

```
let products = await getProducts({skus: [yourSKU]})
```

It works fine with me.